# Using Sourcetree for Flutter project : Why does google-services get pushed?

Tags: git, flutter, github, gitignore

TLDR:

1) why does google-services.json get pushed when its included in gitignore ?

2) if a file does exist in the repo, does it get deleted on the next push, when i include its name in gitignore ?

I am currently trying to upload my Flutterproject to Github via Sourcetree.
After 5+ attempts and different files i think i am going crazy.

Google-services.json gets uploaded every time, even with a gitignore file that includes it. 
This is my .gitignore file :

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,flutter,androidstudio
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=android,flutter,androidstudio

### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.aab

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/
release/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
# Android Studio 3 in .gitignore file.
.idea/caches
.idea/modules.xml
# Comment next line if keeping position of elements in Navigation Editor is relevant for you
.idea/navEditor.xml

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following lines if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks
#*.keystore

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json                                 <--- this was initially #google-servies.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md

# Version control
vcs.xml

# lint
lint/intermediates/
lint/generated/
lint/outputs/
lint/tmp/
# lint/reports/

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs
output.json

# Replacement of .externalNativeBuild directories introduced
# with Android Studio 3.5.
.cxx/

### Flutter ###
# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages

### AndroidStudio ###
# Covers files to be ignored for android development using Android Studio.

# Built application files

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM

# Java class files

# Generated files

# Gradle files
.gradle

# Signing files
.signing/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse

# Log Files

# Android Studio
/*/build/
/*/local.properties
/*/out
/*/*/build
/*/*/production
*.ipr
*~
*.swp

# Android Patch

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later

# NDK
obj/

# IntelliJ IDEA
*.iws
/out/

# User-specific configurations
.idea/caches/
.idea/libraries/
.idea/shelf/
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml
.idea/datasources.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids
.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/dynamic.xml
.idea/uiDesigner.xml

# OS-specific files
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# Legacy Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
.cproject
.settings/

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs (Reference: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml)
hs_err_pid*

## Plugin-specific files:

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/mongoSettings.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### AndroidStudio Patch ###

!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,flutter,androidstudio
```

So as you can see, the initial push was with a commented out google-services.json but as soon as i push it like the way you see it, it should update or not ? If not, how do you automatically exclude files from the next commit ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. It does not exactly answer my question because i couldn't figure out how to do that on sourcetree but thanks for your suggestion.